# I can't use PatternSequence with Cases

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a list of integers:

```
s = {4, 5, 5, 6, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 6, 3, 4};
```

And if I do this, both occurrences of *4 after 3* are replaced.

```
s //. {x___, PatternSequence[3, 4], y___} :> {x, Null, y}
```

But doing the two thing below with `Cases` gives an empty list. What's the correct way to do it? And, what if I want to find only that `Seqence[3, 4]` that follows something less than 6; how should I insert `/;`?

```
Cases[s, {___, PatternSequence[3, 4], ___}]

Cases[s, PatternSequence[3, 4]]
```

**Update:** This is much closer to my actual problem.

Starting with a list of unique integer points.

```
p1 = With[{a = 20},
    Table[Round[a {Cos[t], Sin[t]}],
     {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/1000}]] // DeleteDuplicates;
```

With the help of Mr.Wizard and Spawn1701D I can already find the corner points (redundant for my case), and then take `Complement` to original `p1`. Can this dropping be done directly with `DeleteCases` let's say? (I can see the corner points aren't defined uniquely, which doesn't matter now.)

```
p2 = ReplaceList[p1, {___, ps : PatternSequence[
         {_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, {x3_, _}] /; y2 == y1 && x2 == x3,
      ___} :> {ps}] // Map[#[[2]] &, #] &;

GraphicsRow[Graphics[{PointSize[.015],
     Point@#}] & /@ {p1, p1~Complement~p2}]
```

[image]

Comment: For the first `Case` you have to put `{s}` if you look at the online manual the entry for `Cases` you will notice that `Case` look inside a list for the pattern (or inside the arguments of a function H) and inside your list there isn't the pattern you are looking for. For your last question just use `PatternSequence[a_,3,4]/;a<6`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `Cases` pattern does not match because the default *levelspec* is `{1}`.  If you use `{0}` your pattern matches the entire expression:

```
Cases[s, {___, PatternSequence[3, 4], ___}, {0}]
```

> ```
> {{4, 5, 5, 6, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 6, 3, 4}}
> ```

This is probably not what you want however.  Consider instead:

```
ReplaceList[s, {___, x : PatternSequence[3, 4], ___} :> {x}]
```

> ```
> {{3, 4}, {3, 4}}
> ```

Or with your restriction:

```
ReplaceList[s, {___, n_ /; n < 6, x : PatternSequence[3, 4], ___} :> {x}]
```

> ```
> {{3, 4}}
> ```

This particular pattern can be written more tersely without `PatternSequence`:

```
ReplaceList[s, {___, n_ /; n < 6, 3, 4, ___} :> {n, 3, 4}]
```

> ```
> {{4, 3, 4}}
> ```

I included the preceding value in the list merely to show the match.

---

Responding to your updated question I cannot think of a reasonable way to do that with `DeleteCases` because that function, like `Cases`, operates on elements rather than sequences of elements, which is why I turned to `ReplaceList` in the first place.  I can at least give you cleaner code for `p2`:

```
p2 = ReplaceList[p1,
  {___, {_, y1_}, a : {x2_, y2_}, {x3_, _}, ___} /; y2 == y1 && x2 == x3 :> a
]
```

This does perform better than using `//.` to perform the operation, as there are optimizations in `ReplaceList` to not rescan the same expressions over and over as `//.` will.

---

It is worth mentioning that if you need the positions of the elements you ultimately wish to delete you can do this:

```
pos = ReplaceList[p1,
  {a___, {_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, {x3_, _}, ___} /; y2 == y1 && x2 == x3 :> 2 + Length@{a}
]
```

Used perhaps like:

```
Delete[p1, List /@ pos]
```

---

## Version 10.1 update

*Mathematica* 10.1 introduced [`SequenceCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html) for this task:

```
s = {4, 5, 5, 6, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 6, 3, 4};

SequenceCases[s, {n_ /; n < 6, 3, 4}]
```

> ```
> {{4, 3, 4}}
> ```

***However I cannot recommend its use*** for any sequences specified with patterns because it has serious performance issues; see:

- [Performance problems in new Sequence functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83325/121)

As a concise example of the problem:

```
SeedRandom[1]
big = RandomInteger[33, 30000];

SequenceCases[big, {n_ /; n < 6, 3, 4}]                      // AbsoluteTiming
ReplaceList[big, {___, n_ /; n < 6, 3, 4, ___} :> {n, 3, 4}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {3.38066, {{4, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 4}}}
>
> {0.00441126, {{4, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 4}}}
> ```

Therefore please use `ReplaceList` despite the extra keystrokes.

Comment: What I'd like really is to elegantly drop those *4 after 3* occurrences, this is why I am asking about `Cases`. I've done that now with the help of your answer and conditioning after `PatternSequence` of @Spawn1701D, but what did I do, I extracted those occurrences now via `ReaplceList` and then take to `Complement` original list. Surely I can do this with `DeleteCases`? Wait just a sec, I'll update the question.

Comment: @BoLe I added a small update to my question.  Conceptually I understand what you desire, but practically I don't think that function exists in *Mathematica*.  There are closer operations within the String replacement tools but your need to make mathematical comparisons likely removes any efficiency advantage that would have here.

Comment: Cleaner `ReplaceList`, this is true. Nice alternative to complement with positioning and deleting elements.

Comment: @BoLe to give credit where due I first saw that combination of `ReplaceList` and `Length` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8740525/618728).  Come to think of it that's a closely related question and you may care to read it.

Comment: *And* the alternative I'll use because `Complement` sorts the list before releasing it, pretty. :)