# Need help in building a pattern

Tags: pattern-matching

Suppose I have the following list:

```
list = {w, r, {f, first, t, y}, {a, y}, last, {k, r, first, e}, m, e, last, r, t}
```

I am expecting this

```
Cases[list, {__, {__, first, x__}, y__, last, __} :> {{first, x}, y, 
   last}]
```

to result in this

```
(*{{{first, t, y}, {a, y}, last}, {{first, e}, m, e, last}}*)
```

and this

```
Cases[Flatten@list, {__, first, x__, last, __} :> {first, x, last}]
```

to result in this

```
(*{{first, t, y, a, y, last}, {first, e, m, e, last}}*)
```

but the results for both are `{}`.

How can I build a suitable pattern to get the desired results?

Comment: This should probably be marked as a duplicate of: [(23454)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23454)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cases` is looking for matches *within* the input expression, given the default *levelspec* of `{1}`, or a *single* match to the entire expression if you use *levelspec* `{0}`.  Instead you need multiple matches for the entire expression for which you can use [`ReplaceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceList.html):

```
ReplaceList[list,
  {__, {__, first, x__}, y : Except[last] .., last, __} :>
   {{first, x}, y, last}
]
```

> ```
> {{{first, t, y}, {a, y}, last}, {{first, e}, m, e, last}}
> ```

Note that I needed to change the pattern to `y : Except[last] ..` otherwise you will also match this:

> ```
> {{first, t, y}, {a, y}, last, {k, r, first, e}, m, e, last}
> ```

Comment: thanks a lot. is there any way to get the same result using Cases?

Comment: @Algohi Not in any practical way of which I am aware.